# Python: get the distance between pairs

Tags: python

In our datasets we have big sets of sequences e.g. "aismeorisityou" which we like to get the distance between the two adjacent pairs. So in this case  between the two 'is's there is 6 other letters. What's the best way to go about this?

This is as far as we got..

```
count = 0
for i in range(1, len(x)):
    if x[i] == x[i-1]:
        # True if there are pairs - now count the distance
return None
```

The output should be the distance, 6.

Comment: What is the full output for that input string? why not the distance between that two `isit`s? or the `i`s` etc etc

Comment: @Dan the output should be the distance... sorry if it doesn't make sense. will update.

Comment: I mean just the one distance? Or the distance between every possible repeated pair. `is` isn't the only repeated part and you didn't say that `is` was also an input.

Comment: Yeah, like @Dan's saying, how do you get the pairs? When you say "adjacent" you mean substrings of length 2, right? If so, why only `is` and not `si` and `it`?

Comment: Sorry! I removed the other pair. So the input is now ``aismeorisityou`` and output should be 6.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a second inner loop:

```
x= 'aismeorisityou'
for i in range(1, len(x)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(x)-1):
        if x[i] == x[j] and x[i+1]==x[j+1]:
            print(x[i]+x[i+1])
            print('separated by: ' + str(j-i))
```

returns:

```
is
separated by: 6
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I still think this is the answer you're looking for

Comment: So again, just to clarify. The input is ``aismeorisityou`` and the output should be a number. 6.

Comment: it will return the distance for every pair of letters, since you have 2 i's it will at least return 2 results

Comment: Yes, this is the correct behavior. Can I only get the 6 though?  and not the others.

Comment: what makes 6 different to the others?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212289/discussion-between-user3641381-and-gamopo).

Answer (score 0):

If the sequences are strings, as your example: "aismeorisityou"

```
s = 'aismeorisityou'
```

you can String find (or index) the Substring 'is', and then return both of them.

```
>>> s.index('is')
1
>>> s.rindex('is')
7
>>> s.find('is')
1
>>> s.rfind('is')
7
>>>
```

Write a def, then return the spaces between.

However, what you find with the docs:

```
 |  rfind(...)
 |      S.rfind(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int
 |      
 |      Return the highest index in S where substring sub is found,
 |      such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
 |      arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.
 |      
 |      Return -1 on failure.
 |  
 |  rindex(...)
 |      S.rindex(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int
 |      
 |      Return the highest index in S where substring sub is found,
 |      such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
 |      arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.
 |      
 |      Raises ValueError when the substring is not found.
```